# Is it typical for Java synchronized methods to give preference to the most recent invoking thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

From what I've read, the order in which threads get access to a synchronized method is unspecified and therefore implementation-specific, but it appears that in Oracle Java 8 (1.8.0_101-b13, 64-bit on Ubuntu) that the most recent invoking thread is generally given preference.

For example, when I run the following class:

```
class C
{

    synchronized void go()
    {
        try
        {
           Thread.sleep(100);
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
           System.out.flush();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        C c = new C();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(((Runnable) c::go));
            t.setName(Integer.toString(i));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I typically get results like the following:

0
98
99
97
96
95
94
91
93
...
4
3
2
1

Can anyone confirm that the Oracle JVM tends to do this? And if there's any particular reason?

Comment: Threads are implemented by using processes on most systems.  So it would depend on your OS's underlying implementation.  You might want to ask the Ubuntu dev folks if their semaphores/blocking system show any preference in that regard.  Could be some sort of list/queue for blocked processes.

Comment: What do you mean, "most recent invoking thread?"  Each of the threads in your example calls `go()` and locks the mutex exactly one time.  Do you mean, the most recently _started_ thread?

Comment: Your example does not depict a good use of `synchronized` because it does I/O while holding the lock.  You should avoid keeping a lock locked for any longer than it takes for your program to assign a few variables.  If you follow that rule, then the lock will rarely be in contention, and you won't care whether it is "fair" or not.

Comment: @markspace, What do you mean, "by using processes...?" In several operating systems that I have known, a thread is an executable context (a thread is what the scheduler schedules) and a process is a collection of resources (open files, virtual address space, etc.), and each thread "belongs to" one process.  In the _Linux_ operating system, which did not have threads from its very beginning, the "thread" idea was only gradually disentangled from the "process" idea; but there are other operating systems that have had threads as a distinct entity from the start.

Comment: @jameslarge I've never heard a process called a collection of resources.  A process is an executable context just like a thread.  That it happens to contain open files etc. is just a necessary implementation of OS housekeeping.  The difference between threads and processes is that threads share heap memory space, and processes don't.

Comment: @markspace, You and I are talking at different levels.  It sounds to me as if you are talking about a choice that a software developer would make---whether to structure some application as a collection of cooperating processes or, as a collection of cooperating threads within a single process.  I am talking about data structures within an operating system kernel.  In _some_ operating systems that I have used (and some whose code I have worked on), the object called "process" does not resemble the object called "thread" in any way.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm talking about the design of an OS and its kernel.  Some systems support virtual memory, some don't.  Some support tracking files per process, some don't.  The design of threads, the impetus to make a different type of thing from a process, was the observation that it would be an advantage if processes could share heap memory.  These lighter weight processes were called threads.  It's been a while since I've dug into Linux internals but just because the process control block has extra fields in it doesn't mean those objects are intrinsic to the concept of a process.

Answer (score 0):

No, just conincidence and OS-dependent, increase your loop number to `10000` or some greater number,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
```

you will find totally different result.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` isn't fair in this terms, meaning that there are no guarantees to which thread will enter synchronized section next, according to specification.

Digging deeper you will find out that this behaviour is OS-dependent, however anyway you should rely on it, it could be an optimization which would be amended in the future versions of Oracle VM without any notice, as its not specified, or ,for example, this behaviour could change due to some optimizations performed in runtime such as `lock coarsening`.

If you need strict fair order for accessing critical section you should probably take a look at `java.util.concurrent` package which holds some primitives which has `fair` option, like [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the synchronized monitor acquisition is nothing compared to starting a new thread and unparking from sleep. You should be concerned about how ordered can the OS be with regards to spawning threads and scheduling them after exiting sleep. This has a lot more effect than synchronized.

A rewrite of the test with 10 threads every 100ms and they wait 2000ms, to make sure they arrive in order 2..10 on a locked monitor, would likely show something more or less stable on a given OS, but probably not a portable behavior across OSes.